# Serve favicon.ico and other static files with VertX

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

I'm trying to serve a favicon and some fonts.

```
object Lion : AbstractVerticle() {

    @JvmStatic
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
    val router = Router.router(vertx)

    router.route().handler(CorsHandler.create("*")
        .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
        .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
        .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
        .allowedHeader("X-PINGARUNER")
        .allowedHeader("Content-Type"))

    // some json GET / POST routes here

    router.route().handler(FaviconHandler.create());
    router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create())

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler { router.accept(it) }.listen(9090)
}
```

The `FaviconHandler` throws an exception causing an "Internal Server Error" when I go to `http://localhost:9090/favicon.ico`
My favicon is located in `src/main/resources/webroot/favicon.ico`

```
Oct 22, 2016 11:16:42 PM io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase
SEVERE: Unexpected exception in route
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.FaviconHandlerImpl.init(FaviconHandlerImpl.java:148)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.FaviconHandlerImpl.handle(FaviconHandlerImpl.java:155)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.FaviconHandlerImpl.handle(FaviconHandlerImpl.java:33)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteImpl.handleContext(RouteImpl.java:215)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:78)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:94)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.CorsHandlerImpl.handle(CorsHandlerImpl.java:121)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.CorsHandlerImpl.handle(CorsHandlerImpl.java:38)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteImpl.handleContext(RouteImpl.java:215)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:78)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:94)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.accept(RouterImpl.java:79)
    at Lion$main$8.handle(Lion.kt:90)
    at Lion$main$8.handle(Lion.kt:43)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.ServerConnection.handleRequest(ServerConnection.java:286)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.ServerConnection.processMessage(ServerConnection.java:412)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.ServerConnection.handleMessage(ServerConnection.java:139)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl$ServerHandler.lambda$createConnAndHandle$1(HttpServerImpl.java:712)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:314)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:190)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl$ServerHandler.createConnAndHandle(HttpServerImpl.java:706)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl$ServerHandler.doMessageReceived(HttpServerImpl.java:570)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl$ServerHandler.doMessageReceived(HttpServerImpl.java:522)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.VertxHttpHandler.channelRead(VertxHttpHandler.java:76)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:122)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:372)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:350)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:372)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:350)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl$Http1xOrHttp2Handler.http1(HttpServerImpl.java:1019)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl$Http1xOrHttp2Handler.channelRead(HttpServerImpl.java:990)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:372)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:350)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:372)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:610)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:551)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:465)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:437)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.FaviconHandlerImpl$Icon.<init>(FaviconHandlerImpl.java:61)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.FaviconHandlerImpl$Icon.<init>(FaviconHandlerImpl.java:40)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.FaviconHandlerImpl.init(FaviconHandlerImpl.java:143)
    ... 48 more
```

Removing the `FaviconHandler` and normal `html`, `js` and `css` files are serving fine, but fonts are failing to serve.

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:9090/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
/#/tcr:1 OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header
```

When I go directly to that font-url, the browser is trying to download the font as a regular file.

This seems like a potential solution, but I'm seeing something that is not my favicon, just a 16x16 square with distorted lines in it, the fonts are still trying to download and still giving the error in the browser console.

```
    router.route("/favicon.ico").handler {
        it.response().putHeader("Content-Type", "image/x-icon").sendFile("webroot/favicon.ico")
    }

    router.route("/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff").handler { 
         it.response().putHeader("Content-Type", "application/font-woff").sendFile("webroot/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff")
    }
```

So to sum up, how do I make the `StaticHandler` serve `.woff` and `.ico` files correctly with the correct MimeTypes and not have it download those files?

**Solution**:

First problem I had was that maven shade wasn't copying all the font files into jar for some reason.

Explicitly copying the font files on build and disabling resource filtering for fonts seems to have fixed the font issue.

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/fonts</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Then serving the fonts from the resource directory instead of the font directory fixed it (VertX just wouldn't serve from the font directory for some reason even though the files are there)

[image]

```
   router.route("/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2").handler {
            it.response().sendFile("glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2")
        }
        router.route("/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff").handler {
            it.response().sendFile("glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff")
        }
        router.route("/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf").handler {
            it.response().sendFile("glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf")
        }
        router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create().setCachingEnabled(true));
```

Favicon is probably being cached, still investigating, favicon is not that critical to fix at the moment.

```
router.route("/favicon.ico").handler(FaviconHandler.create("favicon.ico"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Favicon.ico:**

Simply move your `favicon.ico` file up a level into the `resources` folder directly:

```
/src/main/resources/favicon.ico
```

Alternatively change your `FaviconHandler` to pass in the path and filename:

```
router.route().handler(FaviconHandler.create(FaviconHandler.create("webroot/favicon.ico")))
```

Your code assumes that `FaviconHandler` also respects the `webroot` set in `StaticHandler` but it does not.  That is purely a property of `StaticHandler` and therefore `FaviconHandler` looks for the resource in `resources/` unless you specify a relative path.  When that resource isn't found, [it uses the result of `getResourceAsStream("favicon.ico")`](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/09a2463262b46b1826c088624f549b3cbb6f4f01/vertx-web/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/impl/Utils.java#L137) which is `null` and crashes.

If you look at the unit test for the `FaviconHandlerImpl` you will see that [they place the favicon.ico file in the root of resources](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/tree/09a2463262b46b1826c088624f549b3cbb6f4f01/vertx-web/src/test/resources) instead of `webroot`.

---

**WOFF Files:**

As for your font files you are looking in the wrong place for the problem.  It has nothing to do with MIME types.

More likely is that you corrupted the WOFF files on accident.  This could have happened when you committed them with GIT and it thought they were text files and it broke the line endings thereby corrupting them.  Or you used Maven Filter plugin and it did the same, corrupting them.  Or you uploaded/downloaded them via FTP as text files, same problem.

See other posts about this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33792610/3679676

Comment: Maven was indeed to blame for it, firstly maven shade wasn't copying all the font files over for some reason (only half of it), resource filtering was corrupting it as well and even after I got it copying, VertX still wasn't serving from the font directory, so copying the fonts to resources fixed it. See my updated solution in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify your favicon path, so Vertx tries to locate the default one:

```
 if (path == null) {
    icon = new Icon(Utils.readResourceToBuffer("favicon.ico"));
 }
```

Your favicon is located at `resources/webroot/favicon.ico`, but Vertx looks for it at `resources/favicon.ico`

So you can either specify `FaviconHandler.create("webroot/favicon.ico")` or move it one directory up.

Regarding WOFF files, I was unable to reproduce the problem, as WOFF returns with `application/x-font-woff`, which seems correct.

Comment: You posted an identical answer to mine 5 minutes after me.

Comment: Sorry Jayson, took me time to post it. Still, I don't think there's a reason to get angry, since I also provided a way to serve favicon without moving it anywhere.