# FontAwesome and GIT

Tags: git, font-awesome

I am getting:

```
OTS parsing error: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT
```

and no Icons loading when using my FontAwesome in my project. This started with using git for version control. I already tried this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33792610/4439693 and https://github.com/Microsoft/fonts/blob/master/.gitattributes

But no luck what-so-ever. Any ideas?

Comment: This needs more details. Are you loading the fonts in HTML, or using them locally? What command did you run to get the error message?

Comment: Fixed it be uploading the files again from the source. I guess they were encoded wrong before I fixed the gitattributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to upload the files (.eot .woff etc.) from http://fontawesome.io/get-started/ again. I guess they were encoded the wrong way before and adding the

```
*.eot binary
*.ttf binary
*.woff binary
*.woff2 binary
```

to the **.gitattributes** file didn´t change the encoding.

So uploading to font-awesome/fonts and pushing the changes fixed the Issue.

Answer (score 0):

First 
Go to below file and make it  'hideDefaultLocaleInURL' => false, 
config/laravellocalization.php

than 
do set below all code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(themes|modules|css|js|fonts|assets)/(.*) /public/$1/$2 [L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]
```

i hope this work for you i done this problem by this