# Failed to decode downloaded font (Semantic UI React) on production build

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, create-react-app

I am developing a project with frontend on ReactJS and backend on Java (Spark framework). To build server with frontend, I build the frontend using `yarn build` and then, using Maven, copy contents of `build` folder to `src/main/resourses/public` folder, from which Spark serves all static files. Recently, I moved to CRA and since then all icons disappeared on production build.

When I run the project on webpack-dev-server, everything works fine. All icons are loaded as you can see below:

[image: Icons]

But when I build production version of the frontend and copy it to the `public` folder, I get an this error:

[image: Error]

The same fragment on production build:

[image: The same fragment on production build]

My thoughts are that either icon fonts are copied incorrectly at some point, or the server cannot properly load the fonts, which is less probable as they were loaded earlier when I did not use CRA.

Also, it seems that fonts do exist in the website, because they [appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcB3y.png) as Sources in Chrome Dev Tools. However, as I said they might be loaded improperly.

[image]

P.S. I'm using the following versions of Semantic UI. I generated `semantic` folder in `src` directory using `npm i semantic-ui`.

`semantic-ui: ^2.4.2;`

`semantic-ui-react: ^0.85.0`

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue. The problem was that after I built the frontend, Maven incorrectly copied the production build to the public folder

The solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475982/fontawesome-fails-to-load-fonts-locally-and-in-electron-app)